# How to login with mobile/otp using Django Oauth Toolkit

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-oauth

We are using Django OAuth Toolkit with DRF(Django Rest Framework). Now, we want to provide login with mobile number. To authenticate we'll use OTP(One Time Password). How can this be achieved?

- One solution is to directly create auth-token which doesn't look like a wise idea.

Comment: you can create two api end-points. One for creating user and other for verifying OTP. Once the user has been created in database, Oauth2 flow can be initiated to issue access token for this newly created user

Comment: I had created the api for user & otp verification. But in Django OAuth Toolkit(DOT), we need to pass username & password to get the access token. Anyways. we've modified the DOT to handle our OTP login.

Comment: how did you do that @KumarNitin? Any chance you will put the code online?

Comment: @LeonardoSantagada Please see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Since this is the top search result for 'OTP with DOT (Django OAuth Toolkit)', answering this to help others.

After going through the DOT tutorials, and creating a provider, please see if the authentication endpoint (`/o/token/`) is working with `username` and `password`, to validate that the setup is successful, you can use it. If you are not able to generate the token using the above approach, please do not proceed further. Please go through the docs properly, or raise separate question.

Now, if you have been able to generate token using `username` and `password`, create a `Validator` by extending `oauth2_provider.oauth2_validators.OAuth2Validator` like below. The main idea is to override the `validate_user` method of the `OAuth2Validator` to get user using your `OTP`. A sample implementation is shown below:

```
from oauth2_provider.oauth2_validators import OAuth2Validator

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

USER_MODEL = get_user_model()


class MyOAuth2Validator(OAuth2Validator):  # pylint: disable=w0223
    """ Primarily extend the functionality of token generation """

    def validate_user(self, username, password, client, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Here, you would be able to access the MOBILE/ OTP fields 
            which you will be sending in the request.post body. """
        # otp = request.otp
        # mobile = request.mobile
        # user = AppropriateModel.objects.get(otp=otp, mobile=mobile)
        user = USER_MODEL.objects.get(id=1)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            request.user = user
            return True
        return False
```

Now, need to tell DOT about this Validator. Insert following configuration to your `settings.py`

```
# Need the provider to extend the functionality to use OTP as login method
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    'OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS': 'MyOAuth2Validator'
}
```

You can use the `/o/token/` endpoints with your custom fields. Only caveat is, that you might have to send the `username` and `password` fields to bypass the validation test. But you can send some dummy data in those fields.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek, I wish if I could give more upvotes. I was searching for it but my use case was different from `OTP`. After adding `otp` to my search query, I reached here.